# SARIMA with dummy variables for double seasonality

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima, seasonality

I have a series with double seasonality, one daily and one weekly. I modelled the daily seasonality with SARIMA, and I want to include weekly dummy variables.

I only included weekday variables for the times when spikes occur in my data, and dropped the rest.
That's how a long term forecast looks with this model:

[image]

Now my problem: it isn't supposed to have an upward trend like that.
If I don't include the weekday dummies, it stays on the same level (which I want), but with weekday dummies, the above happens and I have an upward trend (in the spikes).

I don't know why that happens. Any clue why that happens/how I can fix that?

edit:

Regardless of the exact SARIMA specification, there is always no trend without dummies, and always a trend when i include "variablewochentag" (German for weekday variable). There are 2 spikes per day in my data, and my data is Mo-Fr, so i have 10 weekday variables. There is also a seasonal difference (65 = daily seasonality) in my estimation, and i have no constant. I have 2080 observations which i used for estimation, added weekday dummies for future observations and then have run the forecast which results in the above picture.

Estimation Output:
[image]

edit2:

http://www.filedropper.com/data_10
Here is my data. Note: the first 2080 data points are my actual observations, the rest are just zeros + the relevant variables to do the long term forecast.
Seasonality is 65 for daily, 325 for weekly.

Comment: Could you include the estimated model coefficients?

Comment: please provide the data   ...... and all meaningful output .  You probably have a differenced model with a steady state positive constant

Comment: @Richardhardy i included the estimation output.

Comment: @IrishStat i included the estimation output. The model is differenced (seasonally), but it doesn't have a constant. The trend doesn't exist if i don't include my dummy variables.

Comment: also added my data.

Comment: i am having problems with DROPBOX please use another app to attach the data

Comment: @IrishStat does this work? http://en.file-upload.net/download-11098994/data.xlsx.html

Comment: no because it requires installation on my part. ALSO please provide the 10 indicator series in the xls file

Comment: @Irishstat I didn't use DROPBOX or any other App to upload to/download from the sites i linked. What do you mean with indicator series? I have 10 weekly dummies. Eviews can make the 10 Dummies out of the column "Variablewochentag" in the xls, but i also made 10 extra columns for each dummy variable (with 1s and 0s) now, in case that helps. Does this site work better for you? http://www.filehosting.org/file/details/526342/Xj68WCEz7M8gG98N/data.xlsx If not is there any upload site/method you would prefer?

Comment: http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=19626618563797446266 another alternative download site for my xls file

Comment: @IrishStat 
 
I just figured, those sites might have ads that try to make you install something (i don't see it because i have an adblocker). But there is always a button where you can directly download my xls file without installing anything.

Answer (score 1):

Your model is way over-specified (kitchen-sink modelling) probably because of your reliance on a simple statistic like AIC/BIC which premises no outliers/level shifts/time trends/constant parameters/constant error variance and many other things. If you have redundant/cancelling parameters like AR(65) and MA(65) as you do all bets are off with the normal expectation of stable (i.e.non-trending) forecasts. Furthermore if your coefficients are non-invertible or nearly non-invertible like your AR(1) and AR(2) this can lead to "explosive forecasts" . Consider an AR(2) model with coefficients .6 and .5 ....which is non-invertible because the coefficients sum to more than 1.0 , you get explosive forecasts . KISS is the order of the day. Model identification is important.

Comment: even if i only include Ma(1) and SMA(65), i still get an "explosive forecast" if i also include my dummy variables.

Comment: If i include a constant in my model (together with my seasonal differencing), i also get a trend. Why is described here: http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/arimaconstants/ Could there be the same problem with dummies?

Comment: I think i know now why i get a trend. I need to difference my dummy variables which i haven't done.

Comment: That is possible ....

Comment: Any luck ... I doubt it    ..

Comment: the trend disappeared after i differenced my dummy variables.

Comment: I don't know any reason for this other than it is compensating for non-invertibility in the AR or MA polynomials ... I would be very "nervous" about promoting your results .....